# Create an .svg screenshot

Tags: 12.04, screenshot, svg

Is there a program that can take an .svg screenshot?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `gtk-vector-screenshot`. According to it's specs it can only make screenshots of GTK3 applications but maybe you are lucky. I used it some time ago and it was fine.

You can install it by:

```
sudo apt-get install gtk-vector-screenshot
```

and run it by:

```
take-vector-screenshot
```

Some sources also say you have to logout and login again before you can use it.

Comment: How do we use it? I installed it but can't find it in dash, neither does terminal finds the command by its name.

Comment: are there any other tools?

Comment: Unfortunately, this tool embeds the captured screenshot from png to svg format. Tool does not really captures any svg paths.

Comment: @AviMehenwal I would argue that there are no SVG paths to directly capture since a screen is alway pixel matrix. If the taken PNG is pixel perfect and than converted to SVG, it should make no difference.